# How to config ipython3-3.2 on Mac OS X?

Tags: macos, python, ipython

I installed IPython with Macport:

```
$ sudo port install py32-ipython
```

It issues errors when I start it:

```
$ ipython3-3.2 
/opt/local/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.2/lib/python3.2/site-packages/IPython/utils/path.py:417: UserWarning: Found old IPython config file '/Users/foouserbar/.ipython/ipy_user_conf.py' (modified by user)
  warnings.warn("Found old IPython config file %r (modified by user)"%f)
/opt/local/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.2/lib/python3.2/site-packages/IPython/utils/path.py:417: UserWarning: Found old IPython config file '/Users/foouserbar/.ipython/ipythonrc' (modified by user)
  warnings.warn("Found old IPython config file %r (modified by user)"%f)
/opt/local/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.2/lib/python3.2/site-packages/IPython/utils/path.py:429: UserWarning: 
  The IPython configuration system has changed as of 0.11, and these files will
  be ignored. See http://ipython.github.com/ipython-doc/dev/config for details
  of the new config system.
  To start configuring IPython, do `ipython profile create`, and edit
  `ipython_config.py` in <ipython_dir>/profile_default.
  If you need to leave the old config files in place for an older version of
  IPython and want to suppress this warning message, set
  `c.InteractiveShellApp.ignore_old_config=True` in the new config.
  `c.InteractiveShellApp.ignore_old_config=True` in the new config.""")
```

How to fix it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have an older iPython config file in your home folder. Rename `/Users/foouserbar/.ipython` to `/Users/foouserbar/.ipython.old` and try again.